# Automatic Birthday wishes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I have a list where in i have the employees name in people picker field and a date column where the birthday is given. I want to send an automatic email to each employee whenever their birthday is.
Please help me on how to develop a workflow for this requirement.
Thank you

Comment: What do you have so far? What is not working? Or are you asking someone to simply provide you with the entire workflow?

Comment: i am simply asking to provide the entire workflow

Answer (score 0):

you can create a SPD workflow - use the action type of pause until {Birth date} - send an email with wishes - reset the birthdate to the same day and month, next year. Hope this helps.

Comment: could you show me this in workflow designer